# Laravel Eloquent wherePivot method returns column 'pivot' not found

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a many-to-many database relationship set up in an existing Laravel installation between users and agencies.

On the frontend I'm using a drop down filter to send an `agency_id` to the server that is supposed to filter/return all the users by this `agency_id` variable.

In my models:
**User.php**

```
/**
 * The agencies that belong to the user.
 */
public function agencies()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Agency');
}
```

**Agency.php**

```
/**
 * The users that belong to the agency.
 */
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

When I query the database, I check if the agency parameter is present in the header

```
->when($request->agency, function ($q) use ($request, $schema) {
    // Determine whether agency_id foreign key exists or if it's a pivot relationship
    if(Schema::hasColumn($schema, 'agency_id'))
    {
        return $this
               ->repository
               ->whereAgency($q, \Hashids::decode($request->agency)[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        return $this
                ->repository
                ->whereAgencyPivot($q, \Hashids::decode($request->agency)[0]);
    }
})
```

In the repository I do the following:

```
public function whereAgencyPivot($q, string $agency)
{
    return $q->wherePivot('agency_id', $agency);
}
```

This returns the following error:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pivot' in 'where clause'

I have also tried:

```
public function whereAgencyPivot($q, string $agency)
{
    return $q->agencies()->where('agency_user.agency_id', $agency);
}
```

which returns:

> Call to undefined `method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::agencies()`

Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer ended up being:

```
return $q->whereHas('agencies', function($query) use ($agency) {
           $query->where('id', $agency);
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to get all the `users` against a pre selected `agency` which is linked with `users` in many-many relationship. Please correct me if I have miss understood.

**To get many to many relationship**

```php
Agency::with('users')->where('id', 1)->get(); // id is injected dynamically.
```

**To conditionally load relationship**

```php
if(some condition) {
 $agency->load('users'); // It'll fetch all users against the given agency.
}
```

**To get only users information**

```php
$data = Agency::with('users')->where('id', 1)->first();
$data->users; // gives you only users collection
```

Comment: All these methods query the Agency model. I need to query the User model. Is that possible?

Comment: These methods get data from User model for the given Agency. So the result would look like:
{agency_id: 1, agency_name: 'abc', users: [{user_id: 1, user_name: 'abc'}, {second users}]} . I think this is what you're looking after